# How to disable file colouring in git-enabled folder in pycharm?

Tags: python, git, pycharm, ide

I use dark mode in pycharm. When folders are enabled with git, the coloring of the files at the left-hand-side project folder looks dark in dark mode. How can I disable file colouring in git-enabled folder in pycharm? It is straining the eyes.

I am using Pycharm community 2020.1

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: Isn't it already addressed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/34352443/6309?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html):**

> **File Status Highlights**
>
> In PyCharm, each file is marked with a color
> according to its state in the version control you are using.
>
> In the editor, each line in a file is checked for its version control
> state and is marked with a color in the gutter.
>
> **[File status](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html#views)**
>
> If you want to change the default file status colors, go
> to **Settings/Preferences | Version Control | File Status Colors.**
>
> **[Line status in the editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html#editor)**
>
> If you want to change the default line status colors, go
> to **Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Highlight modified lines
> in gutter**.

In **PyCharm 2020.1.2 (Community Edition)** the way is:

`File -> Settings -> Version Control -> File Status Colors`

[image]

**Old answer:** You can change the file color from the settings.
Goto `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors&Fonts -> File Status -> (Unkown -> foreground)`

Comment: It's not applicable to Pycharm community 2020.1. Can't find this option in this version.

Comment: Better answer than mine. I have chosen your answer as the correct answer. Thank you. I see you've got 50 bounty points too :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable dark mode for a portion of the PyCharm UI separately. The problem you are facing might be due to wrong installation or something like that. Reinstallation or update of PyCharm might help.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own quesstion.

Go to `Settings > Version Control > File Status Colors` and change the colors accordingly.