# Pycharm project files background red

Tags: pycharm

## The issue

Note, this error is not similar to others whereby the letters themselves are in red, this is where the project files have a red background. See the attached image below

[image]

I believe that this is because it's not marked as a content root

## What I've tried

1. I've tried to set the code as "project root" but I cannot "mark directory as" on right click or within the menu
2. Open the code in CLion and do the same as ^
3. Deleted Pycharm and reinstalled it
4. Looked in the `.xml` (I don't really know what I'm doing)

## Related issues(?)

I've looked up other issues such as [How to stop pycharm show files in project in red color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385143/how-to-stop-pycharm-show-files-in-project-in-red-color) but they are largely irrelevant to me

Comment: Can you change to light-theme and include a screenshot? I don't use dark-mode.

Comment: addressed with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203363/pycharm-python-interpreter-not-showing-anything?noredirect=1#comment120540867_68203363

Comment: Go to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Apperance & Behavior` `>` `File Colors` and check if Non-Project Files color is the same as the background shown in the screenshot. (I think that is the reason, the IDE didn't consider your project as open and thus the files were "out-of-project-scope". In the question it doesn't say exactly what dark-mode you are using so you'll have to confirm if the colors match and this is the case).

Comment: If you have a don't have a lot of special stuff set up in the project, try deleting the `.idea` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to explicitly open the folder again and this makes the red background go away.

`File->Open->${project folder}`

Answer (score 1):

The red background indicates that your Project doesn't know where its root directory is located.

You can set it in `File > Settings > Project: <name> > Project Structure > Set Root Folder` and point it at the root directory of your repository.