# How can i solve "python: can't open file '/app/bot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"?

Tags: python, heroku, deploying

Should be everything correct, but i couldnt find the same problem.  Program on local host (my pc) working absolutely correct.

[it happening when i manually points the command on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKJxA.png)

[bot.py and Procfile both are in the root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbNuq.png)

[heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yit0T.png)

help pls, I'm just studying telegram libraries

Comment: *"bot.py and Procfile both are in the root folder"* - well.. `/app/` is not the root, is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, Heroku puts everything in `/app/`.

Comment: sure , but i dont know from where this part,  there is no such folder named "app"

Comment: @СашаКорчменко, I don't use whatever IDE that is. Why is `bot.py` red? Is it committed? For that matter, why are your `Procfile` and `requirements.txt` blue?

Comment: @Chris  worker : python bot.py

Comment: That should go into your question. Please always [edit] important information in. Comments can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Comment: Then [it looks like you haven't committed `bot.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30385143/354577). I'm guessing the blue files are also modified and require a commit. Yep, [looks like it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html).

Comment: @Chris i fixed problems with colours, commited all the files, right now its same colour.  The problem remained. Also i dont know why the simple  interpreter  start program without problems with file open.  It feels like heroku wants to run a completely different command for another file

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Did you push your committed files to Heroku? _Again_, please [edit] all important information _into your question_. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris thank you for help, i just found the reason why my bot did not start. The last command that was in chat with my bot, was the command which depends from  Pyowm library, when i deleted last command and started bot, all was ok. But now i should find out how to run it with pyowm ))

Comment: That would give a completely different error message. Please, _please_ read [ask]. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.